# Is the Raspberry Pi Pico pinout compatible with the Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino, pinout, raspberry-pi-pico

I could not see any Information regarding the pinout compatibility in the documentation:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/pico/getting-started/

To what extent is the  Raspberry Pi Pico pinout compatible with the Arduino Nano?

The footprint of both boards looks very similar. Many Thanks!

Comment: I will also add that Arduino Nano usually works with 5V, while Raspberries are 3.3V, so you can't even interface one with another without making sure you don't end up sending 5V to 3.3V pin. They are completely different devices with completely different purposes (their computational power is not even comparable, but microcontrollers are small, simple to implement and require much less power on their own)

Comment: Ilya, many thanks for your comment. The Raspberry Pi Pico actually is a microcontroller devboard (Cortex M0+ Dual Core). Good point however, the Arduino exists both in 3.3V and 5v flavors!

Comment: Arduino has 3.3 V Nanos and already develops a Nano with the new Raspberry MCU. https://blog.arduino.cc/2021/01/20/welcome-raspberry-pi-to-the-world-of-microcontrollers/?fbclid=IwAR1O1pcs2kAfLA188Lag72h6B3SDhuO6k5eqvfNNtzGYIlh-CPZL44azcHM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the pinout of Raspberry Pi Pico:

[image]

<sup>Source: https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/Pico-R3-A4-Pinout.pdf</sup>

and here the one of Arduino Nano:

[image]

<sup>Source: https://content.arduino.cc/assets/Pinout-NANO_latest.png</sup>

They are quite different and not compatible.

Comment: Mark, you are quite right. I should have had a closer look. The Raspberry Pi Pico comes with **20 Pins** on each row, while the Arduino Nano has **15 Pins** on each row. Adding to that, the footprint width is different. The Arduino Nano is **7 x 2.54 mm** wide, while the Raspberry Pico is **8 x 2.54 mm** wide.

Answer (score 0):

They are different. Every 5th pin of the Pico is ground.  The Pico is much more powerful and cheaper than an Arduino so it is a better choice.

Comment: I'm not an advocate for Arduino. But I'm pretty sure there are circumstances where an Arduino Nano (ATmega328) is the better choice.